# What does this do? NVL (m-date), to-char(sysdate)

Tags: sql

I'm new to this site I have some questions to ask.

What does this do?

```
NVL (m-date), to-char(sysdate)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Nothing that [Google can't answer](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp). Have you done any research? if so what issue are you having, specifically.

Answer (score 1):

The correct expression is:

```
nvl(m_date, to_char(sysdate))
```

`nvl()` is equivalent to `coalesce()`.  It returns the first argument if not-null, otherwise the second argument.

This returns `m_date` (or whatever the column is called), if it is not `NULL`.  Otherwise, it converts `sysdate` to a number and returns that.